# How to create custom wpr profile in windows 10 universal apps

Tags: logging, windows-10-universal, wpr

I need to create a file logging mode in windows 10. In order to do this, I need to create a custom profile in windows 10 universal apps so that I may change default logging mode from Memory to File and also change buffer settings.

Please help.

Comment: do you need more information/help?

Comment: Thank you for your reply but we changed our approach and now using Metro logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft provides a demo WPR Profile in "`C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Windows Performance Toolkit\SampleWPRControlProfiles.wprp`"

It shows how to configure to log to file (`LoggingMode="File"`)

```
    <Profile
        Description="Sample profile: File I/O activity"
        DetailLevel="Verbose"
        Id="MyFileIO.Verbose.File"
        LoggingMode="File"
        Name="MyFileIO"
        >
      <ProblemCategories>
        <ProblemCategory Value="First Level Triage"/>
      </ProblemCategories>
      <Collectors>
        <SystemCollectorId Value="SystemCollector_FileIO">
          <SystemProviderId Value="SystemProvider_FileIO"/>
        </SystemCollectorId>
        <EventCollectorId Value="EventCollector_KernelPower">
          <EventProviders>
            <EventProviderId Value="EventProvider_DotNetProvider"/>
            <EventProviderId Value="EventProvider_Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Power_AC-DC-State"/>
          </EventProviders>
        </EventCollectorId>
      </Collectors>
    </Profile>
```

To validate the WPRP file, open it in Visual Studio, extract the latest WPRControlProfiles.xsd from the [windowsperformancerecordercontrol.dll](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/matthew_van_eerde/2016/02/09/getting-the-schema-for-windows-performance-recorder-profiles/) and [load it in Visual Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh448223.aspx)

1. Open your .wprp file in Visual Studio.
2. In the main menu, choose `XML`, and then choose `Schemas`…
3. In the XML Schemas dialog that appears, choose `Add`…
4. Choose the WPRControlProfiles.xsd schema.

Later use the WPRP file with WPR.exe:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Windows Performance Toolkit\wpr.exe" -start MyProfile.wprp
```

Run your app and to stop recording run this:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Windows Performance Toolkit\wpr.exe" -stop Result.etl
```

Now analyze the ETL file with WPA.exe or Perfview.