# Not able to find the custom event

Tags: etw, etw-eventsource

I am following the sample provided [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.tracing.eventsource(v=vs.110).aspx) to use the custom event source. However, after I run the sample, there is no event message found in the event viewer like figure below:

[image]

Did you have any idea?

Comment: any status update on your question?

Answer (score 0):

You need to capture the Events with a tool:

- With `xperf`: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Windows Performance Toolkit\xperf.exe" -start UserLogger -on GUID -f User.etl  && timeout -1 && "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\xperf.exe" -stop UserLogger

   Change the GUID to your own
- With [perfview](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28567): perfView /onlyProviders=*MyCompanyEventSource collect
- [create your own WPRP profile and add a entry to log MyCompanyEventSource events](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37360836/1466046) and run wrp -start MyProfile.wprp && timeout -1 && wpr -stop result.etl
- [use EventListener Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.tracing.eventlistener.aspx) to listen to events in your own code
- use [TraceEvent](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.TraceEvent), start a realtime session and subscribe to the DynamicAll Event and parse here the MyCompanyEventSource data.

What you want is to [write to Eventlog](http://www.shujaat.net/2013/09/net-45-eventsource-windows-event-log.html), so you have to set the [`Event Channel` attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.tracing.eventchannel(v=vs.110).aspx)